# Xcode bots cucumber iOS

Tags: cucumber, xcode5, calabash, xcode-bots

i'm wondering if it possible to use any UI testing framework (cucumber based is preferable like calabash-ios) with XCode bots CI. 
I'd like to see test results inside bot stats. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see a working example of cucumber tests running on Xcode bot as well. Another option is to use KIF, here is a detailed tutorial how its done:
http://www.imind.eu/mobile/2014/02/19/ios-integration-testing-on-ci/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use Cucumberish: https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/Cucumberish
In combination with the built-in XCUI or third party frameworks like KIF.
Give it a try, it gives you the beauty of Cucumber with a native environment.

Answer (score 0):

I end up with XCTest UI Framework. Here is some resource:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/